# How to avoid timeout when running time consuming jobs in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-queue, laravel-jobs, laravel-broadcast

In my laravel application i do a form submit to execute a time consuming task by calling `shell_exec(my_time_conusming_Script.sh)` . The process executes successfully on the background. But the connection with the frontent is found to be lost. I find that the form submitting the data stops after processing for sometime. I had a return `redirect()->back()->with('success',$message)`; after the `shell_exec`. But the redirect is not found to be working. if i comment out the time consuming process the redirect works. is any timeout happening. How should i get the redirect working after the time consuming process completes.Should i use laravel queues and jobs and broadcasting.

Comment: Don't run it from a webrequest... use a cronjob for long running operations

Answer (score 0):

Although increasing the timeout may be a solution, I do not recommend it as the client should receive a response in the shortest time possible for an optimal user experience. It is not clear to me whether the outcome of the script execution affects the response to be returned to the client, i.e. with a success message rather than an error message. If this isn't the case, and you want to avoid dealing with queues that can be more complex, I would suggest using [terminable middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/middleware#terminable-middleware), and then return a success response to your client and the middleware will take care of executing right after the script runs. Please note that this will only work if your web server uses FastCGI.

Comment: actually i have these operations: Upload a file, create a temporary csv file from table name entered through form, run a script with these two files as parameters and enerate files from the operation, convert each of the file to pdf. Each of these operations need to send a message to front-end denoting the progress or failure of the operations with messages and/or progress bar

Comment: Then I would leave aside the increase in timeout and add a new model that takes care of keeping track of the evolution of loading and processing. In this way, at the same time as the customer uploads the file, you create a record in the new table, for each job that is completed you can increase the progress and make a change of status. In this way, when the client completes the upload, it receives an identifier that you can recall cyclically to share how the execution of the activities is progressing.

Comment: How can i do it using laravel jobs,events and broadcasting